# Cosa significa "disassare"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Cosa significa "disassare"?

Nel romanzo *Rossovermiglio* di Benedetta Cibrario ho letto:

> Certi la chiamano Torre della Vedetta, benché da lassù
>   in cima non si veda quasi nulla per via di una persistente foschia. In
>   cuor mio, ho sempre pensato si dovesse chiamarla piuttosto Torre
>   della Vendetta. Una vendetta gentile, s'intende; forse nemmeno il termine
>   "vendetta" è giusto, bisognerebbe dire ripicca o rivalsa, e non solo la
>   mia personale ma quella di tutti coloro che in questo borgo ci sono
>   nati e morti negli anni, e che hanno strappato al bosco un metro dopo
>   l'altro di terreno, che hanno scavato con la vanga **disassando** zolla dietro zolla, cercando di non guardare quell'orizzonte di boschi scoscesi,
>   senza fine come le onde del mare.

Non capisco il senso di "disassando zolla dietro zolla" in questo brano. Ho cercato il significato del verbo "disassare", ma non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa?

Comment: Forse l'autrice ha in mentel'[*erpicatura*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erpicatura) che è la lavorazione del terreno che segue l'aratura dove le zolle vengono rotte. La rimozione dei sassi viene fatta solamente su terreni dove 1) ce ne sono molti 2) sono molto grandi. I sassi che bisogna rimuovere sono quelli grossi, normalmente più grossi delle zolle, e dunque "disassando zolla dietro zolla"  ha senso fino ad un certo punto.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Il gerundio *disassando* è assai probabilmente un neologismo inventato dall'autrice per dire il lavoro tenace e faticoso per avere terra coltivabile. Il neologismo nasce con l'utilizzo del prefisso dis- in senso "sottrattivo" (http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/differenze-prefissi-dis). "Disassare" significa qui "togliere i sassi" (il terreno, evidentemente, non è fatto solo di terra e/o è duro da lavorare). Un verbo simile (nella formazione e curiosamente anche nel suono), ma usato più di frequente, è "disossare", cioè "togliere le ossa" ad es. di un pollo, per cucinarlo.
"Zolla *dietro* zolla" significa "zolla *dopo* zolla". *Dietro*, quindi, qui ha un significato temporale e non spaziale.

Comment: "Zolla dietro zolla" indica, credo, il procedere nel lavoro da una zolla, poi a quella accanto successiva, poi a quella accanto alla precedente (_dietro_ perchè l'attuale appare dietro la successiva); direi che comunque  la progressione spaziale rimandi a la successione temporale del lavoro. È una bella espressione, no?

Answer (score 3):

Il verbo **disassare** significa:

> **Disassare**: inclinare o spostare rispetto ad un asse.

L'aggettivo corrispettivo, **disassato**, si usa in linguaggio tecnico parlando di elementi meccanici o costruttivi non "in asse" tra loro.

In questo caso penso che l'autore lo usi per indicare che prima del passaggio dell'uomo la superficie della terra è uniforme, mentre dopo il passaggio le zolle di terra lavorata si inclinano ugnuna in una direzione diversa.

Comment: -1 Mi spiace ma qui secondo me si parla di togliere i sassi, non di variare l'inclinazione del terreno

Comment: Possibile, ma visto che il verbo esiste, e il significato non mi sembra così impossibile da inserire nel contesto descritto, mi sembrava giusto riportarlo. Ma forse è il mio essere ingegnere a influenzarmi.

Comment: Dove si trova questa definizione?

Comment: @Charo non riesco a trovare definizioni nei dizionari online, almeno non per il verbo. Io però l'ho sentito usare molte volte all'università, parlando di  elementi meccanici (sono ingegnere, non fatemene una colpa). Evidentemente per me è un termine comune, ma non è così per tutti. Comunque più tardi provo a cercare altri riferimenti.

Comment: ***Disassato***: http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=disassato

Comment: @Josh61 grazie, era l'unico riferimento online che avevo trovato anche io.

Comment: Avresti più fortuna cercando **disassamento**... non è solo in meccanica che lo si usa, ed in quei contesti disassare viene inteso come "mettere fuori asse". Se sei in un forum di giardinaggio ecc e menzioni disassare però lo capiscono come togliere i sassi (non credo proprio che tutti si siano letti quel libro)... e tutto in un verbo che non si trova nei dizionari...

Comment: @ErikvanDoren interessante! Mi affascina come ogni ambito di interesse abbia un linguaggio proprio.

Comment: _togliere i sassi_ non dovrebbe essere _di**ss**assare_?

Answer (score 1):

Le zolle di terra vanno periodicamente ribaltate con la vanga e spaccate per prepararle alla nuova semina (ed è probabilmente a questo processo che fa riferimento il verbo *disassare* utilizzato), ed è un processo simile al *dissodare*, che di solito però si intende come operazione fatta su un terreno non coltivato da molto tempo.